# Which CMS have Integration with Existing Grails App

Tags: grails, content-management-system, liferay, magnolia, weceem

I have an existing grails app with multiple forms. I need a CMS which allows me to add existing grails forms to this cms and assign each form different permissions. I need to be able to change site template css from admin page. Something like dotnet nuke where you can add existing asp.net page and assign permissions to this page and add custom theme.
Features requested:

- Integration with Active Directory
- Integration with MS Exchange
- Set up grails form security policy from protal admin ui
- change form css theme from portal admin ui
- easy integration with portal

Comment: Have you looked at the weceem plugin for Grails yet? http://grails.org/plugin/weceem

Comment: yes. I think it is not feature rich like liferay and magnolia

Comment: Okay, what features are missing? You may want to expand your question to include those specific features.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what features it supports, but [Weceem](http://www.weceem.org/weceem/) is a CMS implemented as a Grails plugin, so that's an obvious starting point.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Maglev](https://github.com/Bonheur/maglev/wiki/Quick-Start) plugin for Magnolia that you can use, but AFAIK it works only with 4.5.x branch, not with the latest version.

Other then that, if your main requirements are security and being able to pull the theme from CMS, you can deploy Magnolia and your grails app in same web app, configure Magnolia to handle all incoming requests (that's by default) and only [configure bypass inside of Magnolia for cms subchain for url where your form is available](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Request+processing+and+filters). This way Magnolia will take care of the URL check the security, make context available for you and you can refer from your form to the theme that is selected by editors in your Magnolia installation. While this description sounds probably a bit convoluted, it's actually very simple to do.

HTH, Jan